# Using of HttpContext.Current.Session["Id"]

Tags: c#, web-services, session

What's the difference between `HttpContext.Current.Session["Id"]`  and just using a list to save the parametres ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session is available cross pages and cross request on the other hand list is just for one request. They both can store object but they have different object life time.

**Edit**: based on OP's comments

- InProc mode, which stores session state in memory on the Web server.
  This is the default.
- StateServer mode, which stores session state in a separate process
  called the ASP.NET state service. This ensures that session state is
  preserved if the Web application is restarted and also makes session
  state available to multiple Web servers in a Web farm.
- SQLServer mode stores session state in a SQL Server database. This
  ensures that session state is preserved if the Web application is
  restarted and also makes session state available to multiple Web
  servers in a Web farm.
- Custom mode, which enables you to specify a custom storage provider.
- Off mode, which disables session state. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: yes that's what I'm looking for the life time I think that the session is not persistant Is this right ?

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET is stateless. So if you store things in a list that list will need to be persisted somewhere if you want it available after that request has completed.

Think of each request as a new invocation of a program. If you want the data to be persistent across invocations, then you have to store it somewhere.

Comment: how can I store it any ideas!!